# missing data when recording audio on raspberry pi pico

Tags: python, audio, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

i wanted to record audio using `max9814` and `raspberry pi pico` with `micropython/circuitpython` but when i recorded the data, some parts of it lose because it's trying to read the data and write the data into a .wav file and it can not hadle it simultaneously.

the circuit is like below:

| RPI PICO | MAX9814 |
| --- | --- |
| GP26 | OUT |
| 3v3 | VDD |
| GND | GND |

my code is below:

```py
import board
import analogio
import time
import adafruit_wave
import struct
import storage

# storage.remount("/", readonly=False)

adc = analogio.AnalogIn(board.A0)
conversion_factor = 3.3/4096
buffer = []

f = adafruit_wave.open("audio.wav", "w")
f.setnchannels(1)
f.setsampwidth(2)
f.setframerate(8000)

def save(data):
    global f
    f.writeframes(bytearray(data))
    print("done")

try:
    while True:
        sample = adc.value * conversion_factor
        frame = bytearray(struct.pack('>H', int(sample)))
        buffer.extend(frame)
        
        if len(buffer) > 16000:
            save(buffer)
            buffer = []
            print("clear buffer")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("closing")
    f.close()
```

How can i handle it?

Comment: Sadly, you are unlikely to be able to meet the deadlines required to read audio, process it and write it to disk in python with a single processing unit

Comment: I used async but the result was the same, can you explain what is the dealine?

Comment: Your audio should be coming in at a regular rate so you only have the time between one sample and the next to do all the work that isn’t reading samples. If you had a separate processor or core you could offload the work of filing a buffer, but then you would be on a buffer deadline. Likely your best bet is to just record what audio you can into a static memory block _then_  write to disk once you are finished

Comment: The problem is that the memory of the raspberry pi pico is very shallow and i can't save more than 1 seconds on the buffer and im looking for a way which i can run the reading and the saving part on separated cores.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi Pico *does* have a second core and MicroPython actually support it so you could try using that to record the audio at a reliable rate while, but really I think you should just use C.  MicroPython is slow.

Comment: If you really want to use MicroPython, you need to be aware of the garbage collector and see if you can prevent it from running during recording.  You'd want to avoid creating any new objects and just use pre-allocated objects for everything.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Do you have any code related to this?  I really want to handle it with micropython/circuitpython

Comment: For a reliable recording, you will likely want to look at some kind of daughter board that deals with audio

Comment: @fdcpp could you give me some example of that?

Comment: Specific to the Pico, you will struggle. Any open hardware breakout board will be fine, you just might need to Jerry-rig the interface https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/adafruit-vs1053-codec-microsd-breakout-mp3-wav-midi-ogg-play-record?variant=411670081

Comment: This seems similar to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77783261/white-noise-but-no-sound-recording-audio-from-electret-microphone-preamp-on-r), where I made a couple of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here's the thing: your code's trying to do too much at once and the Pico can't keep up. The trick is to split the recording and saving parts so they don't step on each other's toes. You'll use threading to handle this. Micropython on the Pico doesn't support `threading` like full Python, but CircuitPython does something similar with `asyncio`. Here's a quick fix using `asyncio` to manage both tasks without them interfering with each other:

First, you gotta make sure your CircuitPython firmware is up to date because `asyncio` is kinda recent.

Then, tweak your setup like this:

```py
import board
import analogio
import time
import struct
import audiocore
import audiobusio
import os
import asyncio

# Initialize ADC on GP26
adc = analogio.AnalogIn(board.GP26)
conversion_factor = 3.3 / 65536  # Adjusted for CircuitPython ADC range
buffer = bytearray(16000)  # Adjust the buffer size if needed
buffer_index = 0

# Setup for the WAV file
wav_filename = "audio.wav"
audio_settings = {"channels": 1, "bits": 16, "rate": 8000}

# This function records the audio
async def record_audio():
    global buffer, buffer_index
    while True:
        if buffer_index < len(buffer) - 2:
            sample = int(adc.value * conversion_factor * 32767)  # Scale sample to 16-bit range
            struct.pack_into(">H", buffer, buffer_index, sample)
            buffer_index += 2
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)  # Yield control to save_audio

# This function saves the audio
async def save_audio():
    global buffer, buffer_index
    while True:
        if buffer_index >= len(buffer) - 2:
            with open(wav_filename, "ab") as f:  # Append binary data
                wav_header = audiocore.WaveFile(f, audio_settings)
                f.write(buffer[:buffer_index])
            buffer_index = 0  # Reset buffer index after saving
        await asyncio.sleep(0)  # Yield control to record_audio

# Main function to run both tasks
async def main():
    record_task = asyncio.create_task(record_audio())
    save_task = asyncio.create_task(save_audio())
    await asyncio.gather(record_task, save_task)

# Run the main function
asyncio.run(main())
```

This code sets up async functions for recording audio to a buffer and saving that buffer to a file once it's full. It then runs both tasks concurrently, so one can gather data while the other writes to the disk, preventing the loss you're experiencing. The `asyncio.sleep(0)` calls yield execution between tasks, allowing both to proceed without blocking each other.